# Find the most popular date in sql / rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have a model called BusinessTrip, which has a start_date, and an end_date. This is in a mysql backed Rails 3.2 app.

My Marketing people have asked me to produce a statistic which would return the top 10 most popular dates of the year to be on a business trip.

I'm going to create a rake task to generate these figures and email them to the marketing person once a month, and figure it would be easier to write a query in SQL than activerecord, but am a loss as to how to get started with the query. I figure I have to group the records by date with a count but am unsure how to start...

obviously this will give me the most popular five start days

```
select start_date, count(*) from trips
group by start_date
order by count(*) desc
limit 5
```

but this is not a true picture, as it would not report any of the calendar year dates unless a trip actually started on that date!

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try with the following scope, just try convert your sql to rails query.

```
 scope :by_date, :group => "tips.start_date", :order => "COUNT(tips.start_date) DESC"
 @tips = Tip.by_date.limit(5)
```

**Note::** ***Did not test***, If not work please let me know. Wish you will get an idea at least.